# grep a keyword in all .h and .c files under current directory but exclude two directories

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to grep a keyword in all `.h` and `.c` files under current directory `./` but exclude two directories `./stubdom` and `./dist` in the output.

I searched, tried and tested several command; and finally I think one shell works:

```
 find . -type d \( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \) -prune -o -regex '.*\.\(h\|c\)$'  -print | xargs grep map_foreign_range
```

This shell is finding the all .h and .c files AND exclude the ./stubdom/ and ./dist path:

```
 find . -type d \( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \) -prune -regex '.*\.\(h\|c\)$'  -print | xargs grep map_foreign_range
```

However, the above command does NOT work!

(I delete the -o before regex to get the AND operation! )

However, I don't quite understand why it works. I have several questions:

1. `\( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \)`  This is an action of find, but how it works? and why it is not `\( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" -o \)` (I add another -o at the end).
2. If I put the `-regex` before the `-type`, it will print out the .o files, which means that thee `-regex` does NOT work if it's put before `-type`. 
   My question is:
   The find command's option has an execution sequence from left to right?
3. Is there a neater way to achieve my goal: grep a keyword in all `.h` and `.c` files under current directory but exclude two directories?

Comment: [tag:grep] supports the `exclude-dir` option from version 2.5.2 on. What [tag:grep] version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 2.10. I see. Maybe exclude-dir can help exculde the dir but how to get all .h and .c files? I want to exclude the .o files actually.

Comment: You can also use `--exclude` for the .o files: `egrep -R --exclude ".*\.o$" --exclude-dir "/stubdom|dist/" "map_foreign_range" .`

Comment: Hmm, Thank you very much! But it does NOt work. Should I specify the current dir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The `-o` operator is the 'or' operator.  The `-o` after the second path needs another test after it.  The parenthesized expression is subject to the conditions `-type d` and `-prune` too.  Overall, that term says 'if the current name is a directory, and if the path matches either of the path expressions, then the search is pruned', which means that the search does not continue
2. The general operation of `find` is that it searches a list of directories and does certain actions for each name it finds under the directories where the search expression evaluates to true.

   Your current command is:

   ```
   find . -type d \( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \) -prune -o -regex '.*\.\(h\|c\)$' -print
   ```

   I'm going to drop the `find .` part, taking it as assumed for the rest of the answer. I'm also going to use the names `A` and `B` in place of `stubdom` and `dist` to shorten it so that everything's visible.

   We can certainly simplify it by replacing the `-regex` with `-name`:

   ```
   -type d \( -path "./A/*" -o -path "./B/*" \) -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' -print
   ```

   Note that the default connective between conditions is 'and'.  Using the C or shell notation `&&` and `||`, we can see that the expression is of the form:

   ```
   (-type d && ( ... ) && -prune) || (-name '*.[ch]' && -print)
   ```

   When you moved the `-regex` (now `-name`) before the `-type`, you rewrote the expression to:

   ```
   (-name '*.[ch]' && -type d && ( ... ) && -prune) || (-print)
   ```

   So, the reason the object file names appeared was that the print applied unconditionally.
3. My experimentation suggests that the `/*` on the `-path` terms is counter-productive.

To demonstrate, create a junk directory, `cd` into it, and run:

```
mkdir a b c d
for d in a b c d
do
    for file in abc def pqr zyz
    do
        for ext in c h
        do cp /dev/null $d/$file.$ext
        done
    done
done
```

Now run:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' | wc -l
```

This gives the answer 32.

Now run:

```
find . -type d \( -path "./a/*" -o -path "./b/*" \) -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' -print | wc -l
```

This also gives 32.

Remove the `/*` parts of the `-path` operands and you get 16.  Removing the `wc` reveals that the 16 names are the files under `c` and `d`, which are the ones that are wanted.

```
find . -type d \( -path "./a" -o -path "./b" \) -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' -print
```

Thus, applied to your scenario, you should be able to use:

```
find . -type d \( -path "./stubdom" -o -path "./dist" \) -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' -print
```

However, you might do better to avoid `xargs` altogether with:

```
find . -type d \( -path "./a" -o -path "./b" \) -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' \
     -exec grep map_foreign_range {} +
```

This avoids problems if any file name or directory name contains spaces (or tabs or newlines).  You can also work around that with the `-print0` term in `find` and the `-0` option to `xargs`, if your version of these commands supports the notation (GNU does; so does Mac OS X and hence probably the other BSD variants too).

(*Testing done on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with the system (BSD) `find`, not with GNU `find`.*)

Comment: Thank you so much! it is REALLY helpful! Now I totally udnerstand.!

Answer (score 2):

Here I'll try to answer you:

1. I'm not sure why you want to add another `-o` at the end. The line `\( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \)` will be evalued as `True` if any of `-path "./stubdom/*"` and `-path "./dist/*"` will match. The `-o` is a logic `OR`, and it is a binary operator, so it needs two arguments. You cannot append it at the end if there is nothing else.
2. You are probably forgetting to move the `-o`. If you don't put an `OR` between `-type d` and `-regex ...` find will look only for directory matching the regexp. And not for anything that is a directory *or* that maches the regexp. By the way, yes, for find the order of the options is absolutely relevant.
3. I think that your solution is good enough.

To sum up how your line works it is equivalent to this pseudo-code:

```
if(isdir(file) and file != "./stubdom/*" and file != "./dist/*")
    print file;
else if (regex(file, '.*\.\(h\|c\)$' and file != "./stubdom/*" and file != "./dist/*")
    print file;
```

EDIT:

Reading the comments I remembered about the `--exclude-dir` option of grep. Try it. It will probably be more concise solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It's very helpful! I think my script should delete the -o just before -regex because I want to grep the keyword only in all .h and .c files. Based on your pseudo-code, I found my original script is NOT correct. I should delete the -o.   Thank you so much!
`

Comment: I don't think so. If I read correctly you deleted the `-o` before regex. This means that find will print only directories which end with ".h" or ".c". That is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It won't print out anything if I delete the -o before regex. However, from the pseudo-code you write, it seems that the find result will NOT exclude the ./stubdom folders.

Answer (score 0):

1. `\( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" \)` is a filter for `-prune`, so these directories should be excluded.   It can't be `\( -path "./stubdom/*" -o -path "./dist/*" -o \)`, that's probably an error.
2. If you do that, `find` hasn't actually searched yet, so the match constraint is discarded.
3. `grep` also has options to exclude files (e.g. `--exclude-dir`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following command:

```
find | awk '(! (/stubdom\// || /dist\//)) && /\.(c|h)$/ {
    r=system ("grep -q map_foreign_range "$0)
    if(!r) print
}'
```

Comment: That would search the directories but suppress its output. If the directories are big, this solution would be very slow.

Comment: @pfnuesel Agree on that. But the grep part should be the most time consuming part here, and it is only executed for the necessary files..

Comment: Yes, `grep` would be executed once for each relevant file. That's expensive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes but the same is true for the original command too. Also here grep is must be executed for each relevant file..